# sum occurrence output of uniq -c

Tags: scripting, awk, uniq

I want to sum up occurrence output of "uniq -c" command.
How can I do that on the command line?

For example if I get the following in output, I would need 250.

```
 45 a4
 55 a3
  1 a1
149 a5
```

Comment: the sum up value will be the total number of a1 a3 a4 a5, instead of `uniq -c` then sum up, why don't you just `wc -l` to get the total number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
awk '{sum+=$1} END{ print sum}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' file
```

Or just pipe it into `awk` with

```
uniq -c whatever | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

for each line add the value of of first column to SUM, then print out the value of SUM

`awk` is a better choice

```
uniq -c somefile | awk '{SUM+=$1}END{print SUM}'
```

but you can also implement the logic using `bash`

```
uniq -c somefile | while read num other
do
   let SUM+=num;
done
echo $SUM
```

Answer (score 0):

While the aforementioned answer `uniq -c example-file | awk '{SUM+=$1}END{print SUM}'` would theoretically work to sum the left column output of `uniq -c` so should `wc -l somefile` as mentioned in the comment.

If what you are looking for is the number of uniq lines in your file, then you can use this command:

`sort -h example-file | uniq | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

uniq -c is slow compared to awk. like REALLY slow.

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { freqL[$1]++; } END {  # modify FS for that
                                                                # column you want
   for (x in freqL) { printf("%8s %s\n", freqL[x], x) } }'      # to uniq -c upon
```

if your input isn't large like 100MB+, then gawk suffices after adding in the

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";  # gawk specific, just use gawk -b mode
```

if it's really large, it's far faster to use mawk2 then pipe to to

```
   { mawk/mawk2 stuff... } | gnusort -t'\t' -k 2,2
```